# Docker TLS Security on Remote Client

Tags: ssl, docker

I'm writing a client that would use the Remote API from docker to consume the exposed REST services. I want to secure the communications between the client and server. I'm not fully familiar with certificate handling. I have programmatically included trust stores that contain the server's public certificate to my client. I understand that I have to follow the same approach. But I'm a bit perplexed after reading the documentation about it from Docker:

```
http://docs.docker.com/articles/https/
```

I understand that I have to generate two sets of keys, one for the server and the other for the client. Following the steps as written in the documentation of docker, I have the following generated:

```
MacBook-Pro:misc Joe$ ls -l
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 Joe  staff  1743 Nov 19 23:06 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 Joe  staff  1346 Nov 19 23:06 ca.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 Joe  staff  1743 Nov 19 23:10 key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 Joe  staff     0 Nov 19 23:14 server-cert.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 Joe  staff  1751 Nov 19 23:07 server-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 Joe  staff   907 Nov 19 23:13 server.csr
```

What is the difference between ca-key.pem and ca.pem and likewise what is a server-cert.pem and server-key.pem? Which ones goes to the server and which ones are for the client?

But anyways, trying out the following gives me an error:

```
MacBook-Pro:misc Joe$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out server-cert.pem
Signature ok
subject=Dummy
Getting CA Private Key
Enter pass phrase for ca-key.pem:
ca.srl: No such file or directory
6502:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('ca.srl','r')
6502:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
```

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant (from the same docs): "Warning: These TLS commands will only generate a working set of certificates on Linux. Mac OS X comes with a version of OpenSSL that is incompatible with the certificates that Docker requires."

Comment: Do you think that is the reason behind this error?